# Changing Variables in double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I have these particular exercise that i cannot solve. I know i have to change the variables, but i cannot figure out if i should use polar coords or any other change.

Let D be the region delimited by:
$$
D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} ^{2} : (x-1)y \geq 0, \frac{(x-1)^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{25} \leq 1 \}
$$
Calculate:

$$
\iint\limits_D \sin((x-1)^2 + \frac{9y^2}{25}) \,dxdy
$$

I've tried using $u = \frac{(x-1)}{3}$ and $v = \frac{y}{5}$ so that i can replace in the integral the following:

$$
\iint\limits_D \sin(9(u^2 + v^2)) \frac{1}{15} \,dudv 
$$

knowing the Jacobian is $J(x,y)=\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}=\frac{1}{15}$.

But i don't know where to follow, or if the variable changes i've made are correct. Can I use that $u^2 + v^2 = 1$, or that's just for polar coords?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed say now the the region (in $uv$-coordinates) is $D=\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2|u^2+v^2\leq 1\}$. So you've transformed your original elliptical region into a circular region using your $uv$-change of variable. Treating this as a problem in its own right, you are completely free to change now to polar coordinates.

If you think about it this makes perfect sense. Your first change of variable from $xy$ to $uv$ was a linear map. You can think about a linear map as stretching/compressing the $x$-axis and $y$-axis by some scalar factors and also changing the angle between them. Your transformation does this so that the elliptical region looks circular.

Answer (score 0):

Integration domain $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} ^{2}\colon  \;\; (x-1)y \geqslant 0,\;\; \frac{(x-1)^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{25} \leqslant 1 \}$ is two quarters of ellipse $\frac{(x-1)^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{25} \leqslant 1$ which are located between pairs of rays $x\geqslant{1},\;y\geqslant{0}$ and  $x\leqslant{1},\;y\leqslant{0}$
 respectively. Mapping, given by
\begin{gather}
u = \frac{(x-1)}{3},\\
v = \frac{y}{5},
\end{gather}
maps whole ellipse onto disc $K=\{(u,\, v) \in \mathbb{R} ^{2}\colon \;\; u^2+v^2 \leqslant {1} \}$. Polar coordinates 
\begin{gather}
u=\rho\cos{\varphi} \\
v=\rho\sin{\varphi}
\end{gather}
 are useful in this case with ${0}\leqslant{\rho}\leqslant{1}; \;\; {0}\leqslant{\varphi}\leqslant \frac{\pi}{2} \;\;\text{and}\;\;{\pi}\leqslant{\varphi}\leqslant \frac{3\pi}{2}.$ Therefore,
\begin{gather}
\iint\limits_K \sin(9(u^2 + v^2)) \frac{1}{15} \,dudv=\\
\frac{1}{15}\int\limits_{0}^{1}\left(\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(9\rho^2){\rho} \space d\varphi \right) d\rho+\frac{1}{15}\int\limits_{0}^{1}\left( \int\limits_{\pi}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}\sin(9\rho^2)\rho \space d\varphi\right) d\rho
\end{gather}

Comment: Well, i was missing the step of changing the ellipse onto the disc with polar coordinates! I've never seen an example like that (altough i imagine those were the logic steps). 

The p you add, is the jacobian of the polar coordinates, right?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes, $\rho$ is the jacobian of the polar coordinates.